# how to add multiple graphs in amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am new to amcharts and I am using the below code to generate two graphs in a chart.

```
 var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "dataLoader": {
    "url": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/218423/data1.json"
  },
  "valueAxes": [{
    "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
    "dashLength": 0
  }],
  "gridAboveGraphs": true,
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits"
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "tickPosition": "start",
    "tickLength": 20
  }
});

function setDataSet(dataset_url) {
  AmCharts.loadFile(dataset_url, {}, function(data) {
    chart.dataProvider = AmCharts.parseJSON(data);
    chart.validateData();
  });
```

So this works perfectly and now instead of one graph I want to add multiple graphs in the chart.But I do not want to Define before how many graphs I need(No fixed size).So how to dynamically add graphs in amcharts?Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already know the categoryField upfront, you can use dataLoader's `complete` callback to look at your newly assigned `dataProvider` array and create graphs based on the keys in the array object.

```
  "dataLoader": {
    "url": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/SO-41015973.json",
    "complete": function(chart) {
      //get potential valueFields after filtering out the categoryField
      var valueFields = Object.keys(chart.dataProvider[0]).filter(function(value) {
        return value !== chart.categoryField;
      });
      //create the graphs
      valueFields.forEach(function(valueField) {
        chart.graphs.push({
          "valueField": valueField,
          "type": "column",
          "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
          "fillAlphas": 0.8,
          "lineAlphas": 0.2
        })
      });
    }
  },
```

I added an extra field to your data and created a [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/689f1622087adde96f25815fd4fcc43c)  to show that this works.

Comment: If I add more date range period it only shows as points and that point cursor indicates the last value of foo1 and foo3.Instead of that can I have the average been showed?