# How do I draw multiple lines in amcharts line graph using json?

Tags: javascript, json, amcharts

I have an AM Charts line chart with multiple graphs that I am loading from a url.  This works great with the dataloader pulling json for the data, however I'm trying to get the script to load the dynamic "graph" data as well.  I tried the solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015973/how-to-add-multiple-graphs-in-amcharts) but it does not render in the browser.

EDIT - I fixed the javascript (had an extra bracket) now it renders in the browser, data points are there, but not visible and it isn't painting lines.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

css

```
<!-- Styles -->
<style>
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#chartdiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>'
```

javascript

```
 <!-- Chart code -->
 <script>
 var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataLoader": {
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/rate_json.json",
    "format": "json",
    "complete": function(chart) {
       //get potential valueFields after filtering out the categoryField
       var valueFields = Object.keys(chart.dataProvider[0]).filter(function(value) {
         return value !== chart.categoryField;
       })
      //create the graphs
       valueFields.forEach(function(valueField) {
         chart.graphs.push({
           "valueField": valueField,
           "type": "serial",
           "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
           "fillAlphas": 0.8,
           "lineAlphas": 0.2
         })
       });
     }
   },
  "valueAxes": [{
    "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
    "dashLength": 0
  }],
  "gridAboveGraphs": true,
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "month",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "gridAlpha": 0
  },
  "legend": {},
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
    },
  "menu": [ {
    "class": "export-main",
    "menu": [ "PNG", "JPG", "CSV" ]
  } ]
});

</script>
```

html

```
<!-- Resources -->
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href='https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css' type='text/css' media='all'/>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/dataloader-3.19.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

If I use the following javascript, it works perfectly but I need to be able to add/remove Stores dynamically

```
<!-- Chart code -->
<script>
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataLoader": {
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/rate_json.json",
    "format": "json"
  },
  "valueAxes": [{
    "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
    "dashLength": 0
  }],
  "gridAboveGraphs": true,
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "title": "Store 1216",
    "balloonText": "[[title]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletSize": 10,
    "bulletBorderColor": "#ffffff",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
     "lineThickness": 3,
    "valueField": "1216"
  }, {
    "title": "Store 6528",
    "balloonText": "[[title]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletSize": 10,
    "bulletBorderColor": "#ffffff",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
     "lineThickness": 3,
    "valueField": "6528"
  },
  {
    "title": "Store 230",
    "balloonText": "[[title]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletSize": 10,
    "bulletBorderColor": "#ffffff",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
     "lineThickness": 3,
    "valueField": "230"
  },{
    "title": "Store 6538",
    "balloonText": "[[title]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletSize": 10,
    "bulletBorderColor": "#ffffff",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
     "lineThickness": 3,
    "valueField": "6538"
  },{
    "title": "Store 6514",
    "balloonText": "[[title]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletSize": 10,
    "bulletBorderColor": "#ffffff",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
     "lineThickness": 3,
    "valueField": "6514"
  },{
    "title": "Store 1297",
    "balloonText": "[[title]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletSize": 10,
    "bulletBorderColor": "#ffffff",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
     "lineThickness": 3,
    "valueField": "1297"
  },
  {
    "title": "Store 6299",
    "balloonText": "[[title]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletSize": 10,
    "bulletBorderColor": "#ffffff",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
     "lineThickness": 3,
    "valueField": "6299"
  },{
    "title": "Store 5830",
    "balloonText": "[[title]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletSize": 10,
    "bulletBorderColor": "#ffffff",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
     "lineThickness": 3,
    "valueField": "5830"
  },{
    "title": "Average",
    "balloonText": "[[title]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletSize": 10,
    "bulletBorderColor": "#ffffff",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
     "lineThickness": 3,
    "valueField": "Average"
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "month",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "gridAlpha": 0
  },
  "legend": {},
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
    },
  "menu": [ {
    "class": "export-main",
    "menu": [ "PNG", "JPG", "CSV" ]
  } ]
});

</script>
```

Data

```
    [{"month": "February", "1216": 22.8, "6528": 23.65, "230": 23.61, "6538": 23.43, "6514": 23.21, "1297": 23.14, "6299": 23.11, "5830": 22.71, "Average": 23.21}, {"month": "March", "1216": 20.01, "6528": 22.61, "230": 23.67, "6538": 22.54, "6514": 22.91, "1297": 23.59, "6299": 13.87, "5830": 22.7, "Average": 21.49}, {"month": "April", "1216": 24.67, "6528": 24.64, "230": 22.7, "6538": 40.89, "6514": 38.18, "1297": 41.98, "6299": 23.19, "5830": 38.8, "Average": 37.51}, {"month": "May", "1216": 22.8, "6528": 23.65, "230": 23.61, "6538": 23.43, "6514": 23.21, "1297": 23.14, "6299": 23.11, "5830": 22.71, "Average": 23.21}, {"month": "June", "1216": 20.01, "6528": 22.61, "230": 23.67, "6538": 22.54, "6514": 22.91, "1297": 23.59, "6299": 13.87, "5830": 22.7, "Average": 21.49}, {"month": "July", "1216": 21.67, "6528": 21.64, "230": 25.7, "6538": 40.89, "6514": 38.18, "1297": 41.98, "6299": 23.19, "5830": 38.8, "Average": 37.51}, {"month": "August", "1216": 22.8, "6528": 23.65, "230": 23.61, "6538": 23.43, "6514": 23.21, "1297": 23.14, "6299": 23.11, "5830": 22.71, "Average": 23.21}, {"month": "Sept", "1216": 20.01, "6528": 22.61, "230": 23.67, "6538": 22.54, "6514": 22.91, "1297": 23.59, "6299": 13.87, "5830": 22.7, "Average": 21.49}, {"month": "Oct", "1216": 14.67, "6528": 16.64, "230": 27.7, "6538": 20.9, "6514": 22.18, "1297": 21.84, "6299": 15.19, "5830": 18.8, "Average": 21.99}]
```

Example when Working:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is how you're creating the graphs - there is no `type: "serial"` in an AmGraph object, as that value is used for the chart type. In an AmGraph object,  [`type`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#type) can be set to  "line", "column", "step", "smoothedLine", "candlestick", and "ohlc". Fixing the type will fix your chart.

```
"complete": function(chart) {
   //get potential valueFields after filtering out the categoryField
   var valueFields = Object.keys(chart.dataProvider[0]).filter(function(value) {
     return value !== chart.categoryField;
   })
  //create the graphs
   valueFields.forEach(function(valueField) {
     chart.graphs.push({
       "valueField": valueField,
       "title": valueField, //added to show labels next to legend markers
       "type": "line", //type should be line, not serial
       "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
       "lineAlphas": 0.2
     })
   });
 }
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/3e93b47e2a9eb5055186f8ea267de166?editors=1010)

Comment: thank you very much!  Still learning these charts, more versatile than plotly!

Comment: is there a way to loop through the json in AmCharts 4 the way you did in the above answer?  I'm converting the v3 chart to v4 (which I believe is in my best interest) and not that good at JS.

Comment: Yes, though it would be more appropriate to post this as a separate question instead, since the v4 version is a touch more involved and v4 code is completely different from v3. If you want to take a crack at it first before posting the question, [here's documentaiton on using v4's JSON config](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/json-config/) and [documentation on its built-in dataloader](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/loading-external-data/). You'll want to look at the `done` event in the loader to modify the chart setup post load.

Comment: I can do that if I still can't figure it out. Than you